# Why does strong interaction increase with distance?

Tags: nuclear-physics, gauge-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, quarks

I read numerous times that strong interaction increases with distance. But how can one actually derive the force-distance relation from the lagrangian (quark field + gluon field + gauge coupling)? Since I can't use perturbation theory, I don't know what to do with it.

Comment: For QCD calculations people use lattice gauge theory http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_gauge_theory

Comment: As for the question in your title the answer is "because that  is the only explanation of the obervations".

Comment: You *can* actually calculate an effective potential for one quark in the presence of another from a given a Lagrangean. For regular QCD this is nigh impossible due to its non-perturbativity at energies at which such a potential would be useful, but these potentials are used to study e.g. N=4 SQCD, hoping to find techniques that do not rely on perturbativity to make calculations.

Comment: Oh, and of course, +1 for asking a Millennium Prize question on Stack Exchange!

Answer (score -1):

The strong force, described by [quantum chromodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_chromodynamics) (QCD), is indeed a non-perturbative theory at low energies. This means that traditional perturbative techniques, which are typically used for calculating forces in quantum field theories, cannot be directly applied. However, there are non-perturbative methods, such as [lattice QCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_QCD) simulations, that can be used to investigate the force-distance relation.

The force-distance relation in QCD arises from the behavior of the [gluon field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gluon_field), which mediates the strong force between quarks. In the context of the Lagrangian formalism, the QCD Lagrangian can be written as:

$$
\mathcal{L}_{\text{QCD}} = -\frac{1}{4} F^a_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}_a + \sum_{f}\bar{\psi}_f(i\gamma^{\mu}D_{\mu} - m_f)\psi_f
$$

Here in this equation, $F^a_{\mu\nu}$ are the [gluon field strength tensors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gluon_field_strength_tensor), $\psi_f$ represents the quark fields with flavor index $f$, $m_f$ are the masses of quarks, and $D_{\mu}$ is the covariant derivative including the gluon fields.

Therefore, to derive the force-distance relation, one typically employs techniques from [Quantum Field Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_field_theory) (QFT), such as the [path integral formalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation). In this framework, the force between two quarks can be related to the expectation value of the [Wilson loop operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson_loop), which represents the path-ordered exponential of the line integral of the gauge field around a closed loop. Mathematically, this is expressed as:

$$
\langle W(C) \rangle = \frac{1}{\mathcal{Z}} \int \mathcal{D}[A] \exp\left(i\int d^4x \mathcal{L}_{\text{QCD}}\right)
$$

Where $\langle W(C) \rangle$ denotes the expectation value of the Wilson loop operator $W(C)$ over all possible configurations of the gluon field $A$, and $\mathcal{Z}$ is the [partition function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(quantum_field_theory)).

In conclusion, by definition, the force between two quarks can be extracted from the behavior of the Wilson loop in the limit of large separation between the quarks, known as the "quark-antiquark potential". In this limit, the force between the quarks is *proportional* to the derivative of the logarithm of the expectation value of the Wilson loop concerning the separation distance.

Comment: Such a highbrow hand-wavery for such a simple answer...